# Replace regular expression matches with array of values

Tags: javascript

I have a regular expression to find text with `???` inside a string.

```
const paragraph = 'This ??? is ??? and ???. Have you seen the ????';
const regex = /(\?\?\?)/g;
const found = paragraph.match(regex);

console.log(found);
```

Is there a way to replace every match with a value from an array in order?

E.g. with an array of `['cat', 'cool', 'happy', 'dog']`, I want the result to be `'This cat is cool and happy. Have you seen the dog?'`.

I saw `String.prototype.replace()` but that will replace every value.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use a replacer function that `shift`s from the array of replacement strings (`shift` removes and returns the item at the 0th index):

```js
const paragraph = 'This ??? is ??? and ???. Have you seen the ????';
const regex = /(\?\?\?)/g;
const replacements = ['cat', 'cool', 'happy', 'dog'];
const found = paragraph.replace(regex, () => replacements.shift());

console.log(found);
```

(if there are not enough items in the array to replace all, the rest of the `???`s will be replaced by `undefined`)